# Template loading behavior is different between when a key is specified ( or not)

Tags: c#, wpf

I found that depending on how you set the Style for a `FrameworkElement`, the program may or may not crash. Here's the code to illustrate the problem:

`StyleTemplates.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:tabcontrolgrey">
    <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="GroupBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type FrameworkElement}}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />

    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="GroupBox" x:Key="SecondGB" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type FrameworkElement}}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />

    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

`ResourceDictionary.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:tabcontrolgrey">


    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ItemExt1}">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Variables}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GroupOfVariables}">
        <GroupBox Header="{Binding Label}" Style="{StaticResource SecondGB}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:tabcontrolgrey"
        x:Class="tabcontrolgrey.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="StyleTemplates.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemLists}"
        TabStripPlacement="Left">
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TabControl>
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new MainWindowVM();
    }
}
```

And here are the data and VM classes:

```
 public class MainWindowVM
    {


        public ObservableCollection<object> ItemLists => new ObservableCollection<object>()
        {
            new ItemExt1(),
        };

    }

public class ItemExt1
{
    public string Header => "Item 1";
    public bool IsEnabled => true;
    public GroupOfVariables Variables { get; }
    public ItemExt1()
    {
        Variables = new GroupOfVariables();
    }
}


public class GroupOfVariables
{
    public string Label => "Label";
}
```

If you run the above program, the program will crash when you click on the tab control because `SecondGB` style cannot be found.

Now, in `ResourceDictionary.xaml`, use the default style without setting the reference to `SecondGB`, ie:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GroupOfVariables}">
        <GroupBox Header="{Binding Label}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

You will find that the program can run and the style defined in `StyleTemplates.xaml` is applied correctly! In other words, depending on you are referring to a `FrameworkElement`'s Style by a key name or not, the loading sequence is different, and the program behavior is different. This can cause confusion.

Why is it so? Is it documented anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

StaticResource which is referred by Key:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GroupOfVariables}">
    <GroupBox Header="{Binding Label}" Style="{StaticResource SecondGB}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

should be resolved at compile time. It is [StaticResource implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/staticresource-markup-extension)

`SecondGB` is defined in "StyleTemplates.xaml", but it is not loaded in "ResourceDictionary.xaml", so the named resource cannot be found. For StaticResource it results in exception in run-time (is design-time Visual Studio should underline `"{StaticResource }"` usage in xaml-editor)

Default style *is applied* at run-time, because by the time GroupBox is loaded in MainWindow, default GroupBox style is already loaded.

[DynamicResources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dynamicresource-markup-extension) are resolved at runtime. Application doesn't crash even if DynamicResource was not resolved. Also it can be owerriden at any level in visual tree.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GroupOfVariables}">
    <GroupBox Header="{Binding Label}" Style="{DynamicResource SecondGB}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: So you suggest that I use DynamicReource instead of StaticResource ?

Comment: @Graviton, I would use `<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries><ResourceDictionary Source="StyleTemplates.xaml" />` in "ResourceDictionary.xaml", if possible

Comment: @Graviton, in "ResourceDictionary.xaml" - I don't see ResourceDictionary using any other resourcedictionaries

Comment: What if it's not possible, because they belong on different assemblies and more importantly, I need to change the Style ( but not the data mapping) depending on different views?